Windows Explorer selected file or folder highlight is very bright
I just bought a new laptop and I am still setting things up and I came across a very irritating feature in Windows File Explorer. Whenever I select a folder or file in the Explorer, the highlight color is very bright, so bright that I can´t sometimes see what´s written underneath. I have pretty much tried everything but couldn't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated. I´m using Windows 11 22H2.


Is your screenshot indicative of how bright the highlight is for you? That appears to be the same brightness I see. Do you tend to keep your screen brightness high or low? What about contrast (if you're able to adjust that)? While you're using a dark theme, have you tried using the Light theme? Does that suit you better? But, note that I do not have any issue seeing the text colors beneath that highlight, and I have compared my own Explorer in dark mode and my highlight matches yours, so yours is not broken, per se.

@music2myear Yeah, I think you are right. The screenshot doesn't really look bad. I normally keep the brightness of my screen low and I prefer everything in dark mode. I use a ASUS laptop and I haven't found any option to adjust contrast levels.

Laptop screens don't often offer Contrast controls.

Yeah, I know that. So, are you suggesting that there is no other way to control my issue? :(

Doing some searching indicate you might be able to modify the Registry, but I haven't found a value in the suggested registry locations that corresponds to what my current highlight color is, and the consensus seems to be you may have some luck with customization tools such as Stardock, but there is no way in the UI, and probably not a way in in the registry either, to make this change.

@music2myear oh man. That's a bummer

I might also suggest that a different screen may do a better job representing the nuance in contrast, and may do a better job displaying this at the low brightness levels you want.

Windows, over the last several major versions (probably since 7) has removed many of the customization options it used to have for theming, or, at least, removed them from (relatively) easy modification in the Control Panel Colors panel.
While various sources online suggest you can modify registry keys, in my own testing these don't work.
Even the respected Stardock theming software does not state in their documentation (that I was able to find) they can adjust highlight colors, and focused instead on changing border and window colors and other major screen elements, all things the Windows theme does.
While I may be wrong, my research makes me confident enough to post this as an answer: You cannot adjust the Explorer item highlight color while also using the Dark Mode, and you may not be able to adjust these in other theme modes either.
This leaves adjusting other parts of this setup, other factors that you DO have control over:

Turn up the brightness, even just a little: Running your monitor at lower light levels WILL decrease the available contrast range. Turning up brightness, even a little, should increase the apparent difference between the highlight and its text.
Use a different monitor: Certain monitors may have their own issues with available contrast range, and while it is difficult to replace a laptop screen, you can certainly use an external monitor, and one of these may help give the greater contrast you want, at a light level you are happy with. Even a matte monitor finish vs a smooth monitor finish can impact this, though the smooth finishes produce far more reflections and so aren't for everyone.
Use a light(er) theme: Dark mode is good for text, but often at the expense of other elements. You may find that using a lighter theme can help. Also, there are high contrast themes, though I would guess these are a bit overboard in the other direction and will be even less to your tastes.


I turned up the brightness a bit and tweaked around with the adaptive brightness setting. I guess it did the job, thank you for the help!

Glad I could help.
